# Prove that $A=60$, if, and only if, $BC'+CB'=BC$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, contest-math

> In triangle $ABC$ the bisector of angle $B$ meets the opposite side $AC$ at $B'$ Similarly, the bisector of angle $C$ meets the opposite side $AB$ at $C'$.
>
> Prove that $A=60$, if, and only if, $BC'+CB'=BC$.

By the way, it's Olympiad question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By algebra**: It follows from the angle bisector theorem that $$AC'=\frac{ac}{a+b},   CB'=\frac{ab}{a+c}$$

$$BC'+CB'=a \Leftrightarrow \frac{ac}{a+b}+\frac{ab}{a+c}=a$$
$$\Rightarrow  a^{2}=b^{2}+c^{2}-bc \Leftrightarrow A=60$$

**By geometry**: First suppose that $\angle A=60$ By angle chasing $\angle B'IC=60$ and $\angle CIB=120$ Let the (internal) angle bisector of $\angle CIB$ meet $BC$ at $X$. Now triangles $CB'I$ and $CXI$ are congruent $(ASA)$ so $XC=B'C$. Similarly, $XB=C'B$

AND WE'RE DONE.